# Manipulate not working

Tags: differential-equations, manipulate

I am trying to do a ParametricNDSolve, and then plotting some functions of the solution with manipulate.

```
V0 = 10.^(-120); 
V1 = -0.1*V0; 
\[Rho]0 = (3./7.)*V0; 
Vfirst = Function[{N, \[Phi], \[Lambda]}, V0/E^(\[Lambda]*\[Phi][N]) + V1]; 
dV = Function[{N, \[Phi], \[Lambda]}, ((-\[Lambda])*V0)/E^(\[Lambda]*\[Phi][N])]; 
\[Rho]m1 = Function[{N}, \[Rho]0/E^(3.*N)]; 
H21 = Function[{N, \[Phi], \[Phi]prime, \[Lambda]}, (Vfirst[N, \[Phi], \[Lambda]] + \[Rho]m1[N])/(3. - 0.5*\[Phi]prime[N]^2)]; 
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{Derivative[2][\[Phi]][A] + Derivative[1][\[Phi]][A]*(3 - (1/2)*(\[Rho]m1[A]/H21[A, \[Phi], Derivative[1][\[Phi]], \[Lambda]] + Derivative[1][\[Phi]][A]^2)) + 
       dV[A, \[Phi], \[Lambda]]/H21[A, \[Phi], Derivative[1][\[Phi]], \[Lambda]] == 0, \[Phi][-4] == 0, Derivative[1][\[Phi]][-4] == 0}, {\[Phi], Derivative[1][\[Phi]]}, {A, -4, 4}, {\[Lambda]}]; 

phi = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, Evaluate[\[Phi][\[Lambda]][N] /. sol]]; 
phiprime = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, Evaluate[Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Lambda]][N] /. sol]]; 
V = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, V0/E^(\[Lambda]*phi[N, \[Lambda]]) + V1]; 
\[Rho]m = Function[{N}, \[Rho]0/E^(3.*N)]; 
H2 = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, (V[N, \[Lambda]] + \[Rho]m[N])/(3. - 0.5*phiprime[N, \[Lambda]]^2)]; 
\[Rho]\[Phi] = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, 0.5*H2[N, \[Lambda]]*phiprime[N, \[Lambda]]^2 + V[N, \[Lambda]]]; 
p\[Phi] = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, 0.5*H2[N, \[Lambda]]*phiprime[N, \[Lambda]]^2 - V[N, \[Lambda]]]; 
\[CapitalOmega]m = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, \[Rho]m[N]/(3.*H2[N, \[Lambda]])]; 
\[CapitalOmega]\[Phi] = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, \[Rho]\[Phi][N, \[Lambda]]/(3.*H2[N, \[Lambda]])]; 
\[Omega] = Function[{N, \[Lambda]}, p\[Phi][N, \[Lambda]]/(\[Rho]m[N] + \[Rho]\[Phi][N, \[Lambda]])]; 

Manipulate[Plot[\[Omega][N, \[Lambda]], {N, -4., 4.}], {\[Lambda], 0.1, 0.5}]
```

This works fine for some of the functions like, phi and V. But for the functions I am interested in (the last 3), the plot is stuck on the initial value of lambda and won't update when lambda is changed. I also get the following error message:
[image: Error message]

I'm new to Mathematica so there's probably a much better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve so any suggestions are welcome.

Sorry for the bad formatting of the code, here's what it should look like in mathematica
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. `N` is a reserved symbol in Mathematica.

Comment: You should not use capitalized names for variables in MMA. In your case "N" is an operator and creates the trouble you have. Change "N" to "n" and your code will work.

Comment: use lowercase variable names and you will never have to care about conflicts with reserved symbols (like `N`)

Comment: Thank you guys, yes removing `N` fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.